# Associating values from multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a custom object containing three arrays. The first array contains the names of monitoring datapoints, the second array contains values for each datapoint, and the third array contains the time stamp of each poll. The object looks like this:

```
dataSourceName : linux_interface
dataPoints     : {InMbps, InUtilizationPercent, OutDiscardPercent, OutMbps, StatusFlap...}
values         : {0.0121 0.0001 0.0 0.0156 0.0002 0.0 4294967295 1138904370 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0833 1511.5917 2.6167 0.0
                 0.0 0.0 0.0 1950.1667 2.9583 10000.0 1.0 1142955859 0.0, 0.0018 0.0 0.0 0.0011 0.0 0.0 4294967295
                 1138904370 0.0 0.9917 0.0 0.9917 226.7833 0.425 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 131.525 0.325 10000.0 1.0 1142943859
                 0.0, 0.001 0.0 0.0 0.0005 0.0 0.0 4294967295 1138904370 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 127.0833 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
                 58.3333 0.2 10000.0 1.0 1142931859 0.0, 0.0061 0.0001 0.0 0.0155 0.0002 0.0 4294967295 1138904370 0.0
                 1.0 0.0 1.2 762.4417 1.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1936.5667 2.2083 10000.0 1.0 1142919858 0.0...}
time           : {1567700449000, 1567700329000, 1567700209000, 1567700089000...}
nextPageParams :
```

I am trying to count the number of times the value of "StatusFlap" is "1" in a given amount of time (say, 10 minutes). Using the following code (where $datapoints in my object), I can get all of the values, but I do not know how to line those up with timestamps. Any thoughts?

```
$index = [array]::indexOf($datapoints.datapoints, 'StatusFlap')

$values = Foreach ($obj in $datapoints.values) {
    $obj[$index]
}
```

A sample of the object in JSON format, looks like this:

```
{
    "dataSourceName":  "linux_interface",
    "dataPoints":  [
                       "InMbps",
                       "InUtilizationPercent",
                       "OutDiscardPercent",
                       "OutMbps",
                       "OutUtilizationPercent",
                       "StatusFlap",
                       "BasicSpeed",
                       "ifLastChange",
                       "InBroadcastPkts",
                       "InDiscards",
                       "InErrors",
                       "InMulticastPkts",
                       "InOctets",
                       "InUcastPkts",
                       "OutBroadcastPkts",
                       "OutDiscards",
                       "OutErrors",
                       "OutMulticastPkts",
                       "OutOctets",
                       "OutUcastPkts",
                       "Speed",
                       "Status",
                       "sysUptime",
                       "InDiscardPercent"
                   ],
    "values":  [
                   [
                       0.0121,
                       0.0001,
                       0.0,
                       0.0156,
                       0.0002,
                       0.0,
                       4294967295,
                       1138904370,
                       0.0,
                       1.0,
                       0.0,
                       1.0833,
                       1511.5917,
                       2.6167,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       1950.1667,
                       2.9583,
                       10000.0,
                       1.0,
                       1142955859,
                       0.0
                   ],
                   [
                       0.0018,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0011,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       4294967295,
                       1138904370,
                       0.0,
                       0.9917,
                       0.0,
                       0.9917,
                       226.7833,
                       0.425,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       131.525,
                       0.325,
                       10000.0,
                       1.0,
                       1142943859,
                       0.0
                   ],
                   [
                       0.001,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0005,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       4294967295,
                       1138904370,
                       0.0,
                       1.0,
                       0.0,
                       1.0,
                       127.0833,
                       0.3,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       0.0,
                       58.3333,
                       0.2,
                       10000.0,
                       1.0,
                       1142931859,
                       0.0
                   ],
    "time":  [
                 1567700449000,
                 1567700329000,
                 1567700209000
             ],
    "nextPageParams":  ""
}
```

Comment: Is the second arrays' length the same the third arrays' length?

Comment: The first array is is the list of datapoints. It has 24 items. The second array is a collection of values matching the first array. It has 30 items, each with 24 entries. I'll throw a sample of the JSON into my original post.